# Convert .urdf to .sdf or load .urdf

Tags: sdformat

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I am working on my bachelor-thesis and have a .urdf model I want to load.
First I tried `gzsdf convert *.urdf` an got the error `[Converter.cc:50]   Unable to determine original SDF version`.
I would also be happy if I can load the .urdf model.

There are different solutions to this problem, but I found no one without ROS. (I use Gazebo without ROS.)

Do you know, what I can do?
Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2282/convert-.urdf-to-.sdf-or-load-.urdf/) by [Zwilling](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/302/zwilling/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-04-08

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) on 2013-04-09**:
can you post the urdf file?

**Comment by [Zwilling](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/302/zwilling/) on 2013-04-19**:
The file I want to convert can be found here: http://svn.openrobotino.org/robotino-ros-pkg/trunk/robotino/robotino_description/urdf/robotino.urdf

**Comment by [Ben B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/136/ben-b/) on 2013-04-24**:
What version of Gazebo are you using?

**Comment by [Zwilling](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/302/zwilling/) on 2013-04-30**:
I use Gazebo 1.5.0

**Comment by [Ben B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/136/ben-b/) on 2013-05-06**:
I would try upgrading to the latest Gazebo -- though back up anything important.  That way, the behaviour of our Gazebo installs will be more likely to coincide.

**Comment by [Andrew Hundt](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/685/andrew-hundt/) on 2017-06-05**:
updated http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/16376/whats-up-with-sdf-urdf-model-and-world-files/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

In newer versions of gazebo, the correct syntax is

```
gz sdf -p /my_urdf.urdf > /my_sdf.sdf
```

---

Originally posted by [Kukanani](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3181/kukanani/) with karma: 36 on 2017-10-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Try:

```
gzsdf print urdfname.urdf > newname.sdf
```

---

Originally posted by [Ben B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/136/ben-b/) with karma: 175 on 2013-04-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Zwilling](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/302/zwilling/) on 2013-04-19**:
This results in
"Warning [parser.cc:377] SDF has no  element in file[/home/zwilling/.gazebo/models/Robotino/RobotinoModel/urdf/robotino.urdf]
Error: SDF parsing the xml failed"

**Comment by [Ben B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/136/ben-b/) on 2013-04-19**:
Zwilling, I get the same error using gzsdf print on your file. But, it still outputs an SDF for me. I can't use the SDF because I don't have the associated meshes, but maybe you can.  Let me know if it works.

**Comment by [Zwilling](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/302/zwilling/) on 2013-04-20**:
It produces an empty SDF for me.
You can find everythis associated to the model in http://svn.openrobotino.org/robotino-ros-pkg/trunk/robotino/robotino_description

**Comment by [liangfok](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/51/liangfok/) on 2016-11-03**:
The latest command is:

```
gz sdf -p foo.urdf > foo.sdf
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi ,
I use urdf mostly. But I founnd this easy method where I opened gazebo. then I insert the model and I save it as a world. this generates a sdf file that has the complete completly saves the urdf in sdf format.

I tried running a plugin on it and that worked too. But I am not sure if I should expect any later problems with this.

-Bharadwaj

---

Originally posted by [Bharadwaj Ramesh](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/154/bharadwaj-ramesh/) with karma: 51 on 2013-04-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Zwilling](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/302/zwilling/) on 2013-04-20**:
How do you load an URDF file? How does the model.config look like?
I get an error if I don't have a ... in teh model.config.
If I put the .urdf in the ... I get
Warning [parser.cc:377] SDF has no  element in file[/home/zwilling/.gazebo/models/RobotinoModelChangedURDF/model.urdf]
Error [ModelMaker.cc:123] Unable to load file[/home/zwilling/.gazebo/models/RobotinoModelChangedURDF/model.urdf]
in Gazebo

**Comment by [Bharadwaj Ramesh](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/154/bharadwaj-ramesh/) on 2013-04-23**:
I have a manifest.xml which looks like this :